# UML: Draw sequence diagram

Tags: visual-studio, uml, analytics, sequence-diagram

I have a quiz system scenario and I have drown my Use case, now I want to draw a sequence diagram which describe the the choosing quiz by student as following:

1. student will see a list of available teachers in the system.
2. student will choose a specific teacher and the system will show the
   available quizzes.
3. the student will choose a specific quiz.
4. the system will return the question and the available answers to the
   student to answer them later.

### How I can represent the previous scenario in sequence diagram,I know the essential of sequence diagram but I don't know I can apply that on my scenario.

Edit: The following diagram is my attempt.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Refine the problem by **identifying other actors that constitute the "system"**. Quiz, Question and Answer look like data objects that will be transferred throughout the system, with no activity or behavior of their own, it is not likely there will be any special messages they receive or send.

Similarly to how http://www.uml-diagrams.org/sequence-diagrams-examples.html#facebook-authentication refines original use case "system authenticates user using his facebook account"

[image]

where the original abstract term "system" expands into "WebBrowser", "Application", "Facebook Authorization Server", "Facebook Content Server" which can be further refined down into more concrete classes which will turn into actual code

Answer (score 1):

Sequence diagram is drawn between the objects who interact with each other. Here in your scenario **The student will interact with system and not with the teachers or quizes**. So the sequence diagram of your scenario will be like this:

[image]**